# sql full text search on specific rows

Tags: sql, full-text-search, rows

I am building a web site. I am using sql to store my data. Can I use full text search on specific rows (dynamically determined by user preferences)?
Meaning I want to use the 'where' clause right before I free text search.

Comment: Yes, but for a larger database it will become slow. If you want text search on a larger database you might want to use Solr (http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

Comment: @TTT Meaning I want to use the 'where' clause right before I free text search.

Comment: @mashtagidi:are you querying a table whose data changes frequently ?

Comment: I think we may need to see an example of what you're trying to accomplish.  You need to know that SQL doesn't really use short-circuit logic, like most imperative languages do; the optimizer is usually free to re-order things for performance reasons.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2? They all have different ways to do a full text search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot select a subset of your rows before running a full-text query on it. If you take a look at the query plan generated you will see that the full-text execution is at the bottom of the tree with results being filtered up to the WHERE clause.

Since the row selection is 'dynamically determined' creating a ft-index on a view of the table doesn't seem to be an option either.